# how do I add delimiters to both sides of a tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, delimiters, tikz-matrix

Here is a simple document which does not seem to display properly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\tikz \node[matrix of nodes] { |[left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)]| x \\ };
\end{document}
```

This document renders as [image: incorrect spacing]. When I include just a left delimiter or just a right delimiter, it seems to work okay; namely, I get [image: correct left delimiter] and [image: correct right delimiter], respectively. How can I get both of those delimiters to appear in the appropriate positions?

Comment: Don't you want the delimiters for the matrix itself? I.e. `\tikz \matrix[matrix of nodes,left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] { x \\ };`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Nope, I want delimiters on each node in the matrix. I'm using the matrix library primarily to simplify positioning, rather than to typeset an actual matrix.

Comment: Ok. Your code compiles fine here by the way, with an updated TeX Live 2013.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Strange. I'm also using TeXLive 2013, specifically 0.1.20130608_r30832.fc19. I wonder what the difference is.

Comment: I don't know. You don't have any old versions of `pgf`/TikZ lying around somewhere, do you? By adding `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` you'll get a list of packages used and their versions printed near the end of the log-file. I have `pgf` 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

I propose the following approach. It uses the *tikz*-styles and keeps your code that places the nodes clean.

With the `outer sep` option you can fine tune the position of your `right delimiter` and `left delimiter`. You also can use the `draw` option here to show the node's size for debugging your styles.

I prefer doing it this way, because you can define your styles with heavy fine tuning while keeping your `\matrix` / `\node`-placing code clean.

The following example contains some additional `outer sep`s to show the impact of this option to the rendered image.

```
\documentclass[border=6mm, 11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
 \tikzset{
  braces/.style = {
   outer sep=-1pt,
   left delimiter=(,
   right delimiter=),
   align=center,
  },
 }

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix {
   \node [braces] (a) {A}; &
   \node [braces, outer sep=0pt] (b) {B}; \\
   \node [braces, outer sep=5pt] (c) {C}; &
   \node [braces, outer sep=-2pt] (d) {D}; \\
  };
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Rendered image:

[image: Rendered image code]